# replace NA with fixed values in R data frame for filtered months?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following `data.frame` where I am trying to `replace` the `filtered` months with a fixed value **-1.2345** but its throwing error. I feel the `replace` function is used wrongly but can someone have a look at it and suggest a fix? Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 A1 = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
                 separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
                 mutate(Month = as.numeric(Month)) %>% 
                 mutate(replace(Month %in% c(1, 2, 11, 12), -1.2345))
```

Answer (score 1):

We need the first argument `x` as `Month`

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 A1 = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
                 separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
                 mutate(Month = as.numeric(Month)) %>% 

  mutate(Month = replace(Month, Month %in% c(1, 2, 11, 12), -1.2345))
```

-output

```
> head(DF)
  Year   Month Day       A1
1 2001 -1.2345  01 2.817074
2 2001 -1.2345  02 4.023626
3 2001 -1.2345  03 3.245398
4 2001 -1.2345  04 2.558662
5 2001 -1.2345  05 4.001480
6 2001 -1.2345  06 4.311695
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I would like to set the value of `A1` for those filtered months as `-1.2345`. Also, anyway to fix the entire year of 2001 set to that fixed value in addition?

Comment: @Hydro In that case, it is `replace(Month, Year == 2001, -1.2345)`

Comment: @Hydro you edited the comment.  Sorry,  You can use `A1 = replace(A1, Month %in% c(1, 2, 11, 12), -1.2345))`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `ifelse` instead of `replace`

```r
data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2003-12-31"), by = "day"),
                 A1 = runif(1095,1,5)) %>% 
  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
  mutate(Month = ifelse(as.numeric(Month) %in% c(1, 2, 11, 12),-1.2345, as.numeric(Month))
         )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
    Year   Month Day       A1
1   2001 -1.2345  01 1.413579
2   2001 -1.2345  02 1.572394
3   2001 -1.2345  03 1.698503
4   2001 -1.2345  04 3.314275
5   2001 -1.2345  05 4.929962
6   2001 -1.2345  06 3.866475
7   2001 -1.2345  07 4.897664
8   2001 -1.2345  08 3.642567
9   2001 -1.2345  09 1.270269
10  2001 -1.2345  10 2.198702
11  2001 -1.2345  11 4.407240
12  2001 -1.2345  12 3.739327
13  2001 -1.2345  13 3.619933
14  2001 -1.2345  14 1.001599
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 845 rows ]
```